# Can code128 or other style barcode be embedded in a 2D barcode, and the 2D barcode be used as a location or a Zone?

Tags: qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing, code128

I am working on an inventory solution to take the place of a paper and pen/manual inventory, and am leaning towards barcodes and hand scanners. Essentially, placing code128 styles on our products will cover what we need. However, I'd like to hang a large sign or placard above the locations in a warehouse, where these products/pallets will be stored, so that when scanned, we can then see a summary of what is at that location. This would help tremendously with picking and finding products.

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated

have tried 2D barcode generation with Excel plugin but failed.

Comment: Do you mean literally "code 128 in the center of QR" as seen with many logos ? Or do you mean "the content of the code 128 in the content of the QR" ?  If the first, then yes of course.  Note that code128 needs quiet zones. Also the scanner should be told when to look for 1d and / or 2d, if you are using the same. That may be confusing.  Try to explain clearer by example what you need.

Comment: For example, the product is tie-down straps at various lengths, but often look the same, and stored in that same type of container even though they're not always the same. taking the existing manually printed sheet that's placed on each container and just summarizing that information into a single-line barcode seems like the way to go. Grouping them into "zones" IE "X" zone is for neon green 1in, neon green 2in, and so on is what I'm leaning towards but here's where the nuance comes in (and also my limited knowledge of barcodes).

Comment: The product can be taken, cut, and then put back with the changed quantity in feet applied and updated in the barcode. Currently, we have bartender software and That's what I've been using for the generation of the 128 barcodes but after your comment about quiet zones I'll have to go back and look at it. The other part is where these products are placed - I'd like a quick way to be able to scan a barcode (could be QR or something that holds a lot of information) and be able to see everything in that "zone" so that the operators can stop using so much time searching for the right product.